# Angular: redirect to another page without page update

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router

I have EditUserComponent with path parameter id. I want to redirect to home or error page when id is invalid, how can I achieve that without updating page? Currently I have this code, but it's reloading on home page.

```
constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute, private router: Router, private userService: UserService) {
    this.route.params.subscribe(params => this.id = params.id);
    if (!this.id || isNaN(this.id)) {
      this.router.navigate(['/home']);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you also share your route paths array?

Answer (score 1):

use snapshot of route object

```
this.id = this.route.snapshot.params["id"]
```

otherwise your `if` condition always returns true, or you can do like this:

```
this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
    this.id = params.id;
    if (!this.id || isNaN(this.id)) {
      this.router.navigate(['/home']);    
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I have not seen you router code but I guess you dont need a blackslash in redirect path

```
 this.router.navigate(['home']);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use SetTimeOut

```
constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute, private router: Router, private userService: UserService) {
    this.route.params.subscribe(params => this.id = params.id);
    if (!this.id || isNaN(this.id)) {
 setTimeout(()=>{ this.router.navigate(['/home']);},1000);

    }
}
```

Example:https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-router-basic-example